# pandas fillna based on condition from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, fillna

## Table 1

| ID | Condition | Access1 | Access2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | nan | nan |
| 2 | aa | nan | nan |
| 3 | bb | nan | nan |
| 4 | bb | nan | nan |
| 5 | aa | nan | nan |
| 6 | bb | nan | nan |
| 7 | aa | nan | nan |

## Table 2

| Name | Condition | Accessor1 | Accessor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | aa | Yes | No |
| Mary | aa | No | Yes |
| Bob | aa | Yes | Yes |
| Ben | bb | Yes | Yes |
| Peter | bb | No | Yes |

Table 1 contains the condition.

Table 2 contains the condition and the name of the accessors with their authorization. Either they can access to 1 or 2 or both.

For example, John can access to 1 but not 2, so we have to match the condition of Table 1. ID 1 condition is 'aa', so John can access1 and his name is not fill in access2 and continue to find for other name who has access to it. Mary's condition is 'aa' and has access to 2 so her name is filled in access2.

Bob's condition is 'aa' and ID 2 is 'aa'. Bob has access to 1 or 2. Hence, his name is filled in ID 2's access1 and access2.

ID 5, since Bob is the last name with condition 'aa'. Hence, it will loop back to John again. Same goes to the rest.

## **Result Table**

| ID | Condition | Access1 | Access2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | John | Mary |
| 2 | aa | Bob | Bob |
| 3 | bb | Ben | Ben |
| 4 | bb | Ben | Peter |
| 5 | aa | John | Mary |
| 6 | bb | Ben | Ben |
| 7 | aa | Bob | Bob |

Comment: The logic is unclear, please break it down row by row how you would do it with pen and paper.

Comment: You have changed the example but not better explained the logic. Also the pairs of ID/Condition in the output are different from those in the input, which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: Your logic is not clear. But basically, you need to `merge` the two dataframe and then perform the fillna in the same dataframe

Comment: @mozway sorry for the confusion, but the answer below is working, or there are still ways to optimize the solution.

Comment: @user23638854 no idea, until the question has a clear explanation with a step by step explanation of the logic, I'm not going to give it a try.

Comment: @mozway sorry, this time I have tried to explain it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to create a `cyclic lists` for a condition using **table 2** and then fill **table 1**. My solution is mix of use of conditional statements and pandas broadcasting concept.

Let take example we want to fill `table 1` column `Access1` with condition `aa`,

- From `table 2` with condition `aa` we have three name to fill `[John, Mary, Bob]`
- But with `Accessor1` column condition we are only able fill `table 1` with `[John, Bob]`

**1. Convert Accessor columns of table 2 into `dtype bool` so that we can use pandas boolean indexing to create conditons**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle

table_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": list(range(1, 7)),
        "Condition": ['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'aa', 'bb'],
        "Access1": [np.nan]*6,
        "Access2": [np.nan]*6
    }
)

table_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ['John', 'Mary', 'Bob', 'Ben', 'Peter'],
        "Condition": ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb'],
        "Accessor1": ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
        "Accessor2": ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes']
    }
)

table_2['Accessor1'] = table_2['Accessor1'].apply(lambda x: True if x == 'Yes' else False)
table_2['Accessor2'] = table_2['Accessor2'].apply(lambda x: True if x == 'Yes' else False)
```

**2. Creating lists from which we are allowed to fill the column**

```
condition_aa = table_2[table_2['Condition'] == 'aa']
condition_bb = table_2[table_2['Condition'] == 'bb']
condition_aa_access1 = condition_aa['Name'][condition_aa['Accessor1']].to_list()
condition_aa_access2 = condition_aa['Name'][condition_aa['Accessor2']].to_list()
condition_bb_access1 = condition_bb['Name'][condition_bb['Accessor1']].to_list()
condition_bb_access2 = condition_bb['Name'][condition_bb['Accessor2']].to_list()
```

**3. Converting list to circular list so that we can fill values of column which require more row to fill than what we have in our hand**

```
condition_aa_access1_cycle = cycle(condition_aa_access1)
condition_bb_access1_cycle = cycle(condition_bb_access1)
condition_aa_access2_cycle = cycle(condition_aa_access2)
condition_bb_access2_cycle = cycle(condition_bb_access2)
condition_access1 = []
```

**4. Creating column size list based on condition**

```
for i in range(6):
    if table_1.loc[i, 'Condition'] == 'aa':
        condition_access1.append(next(condition_aa_access1_cycle))
    else:
        condition_access1.append(next(condition_bb_access1_cycle))

condition_access2 = []
for i in range(6):
    if table_1.loc[i, 'Condition'] == 'aa':
        condition_access2.append(next(condition_aa_access2_cycle))
    else:
        condition_access2.append(next(condition_bb_access2_cycle))
```

**4. Finally filling na with above list**

```
table_1.loc[table_1.Access1.isnull(), 'Access1'] = condition_access1
table_1.loc[table_1.Access2.isnull(), 'Access2'] = condition_access2

table_1
```

**Results**

```
 ID Condition Access1 Access2
  1        aa    John    Mary
  2        aa     Bob     Bob
  3        bb     Ben     Ben
  4        bb     Ben   Peter
  5        aa    John    Mary
  6        bb     Ben     Ben
```

**Note:** Lot of things are here to optimize here, would love to know new solution that full depends upon pandas concept at all.